# Runtime Error(NZEC) Error in Python Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime-error

Given below is my code in Python3 for a Codechef challenge:

```
from itertools import groupby
counter=int(input())
arg=[]
p=[]
for i in range(int(counter)):
    arg.append(input())
num=0
while (num<counter):
    x=arg[num]
    l=x.replace('=','')
    groups=groupby(y)
    result = [(label, sum(1 for _ in group)) for label, group in groups]
    for i in range(0,len(result)):
        p.append(result[i][1])
    print (max(p)+1)
    p=[]
    num+=1
```

I am encountering a Runtime Error(NZEC) for four of the eight test cases.
I already checked on the https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/7593/why-do-i-get-an-nzec,but could not find the solution to this problem.Any help would be great.Thanks in advance.

EDIT1:
I fixed the Traceback and it is still giving NZEC in two out of four cases.The code is:

```
from itertools import groupby
counter=int(input())
arg=[]
p=[]
for i in range(int(counter)):
    arg.append(input())
num=0
while (num<counter):
    x=arg[num]
    l=x.replace('=','')
    groups=groupby(l)
    result = [(label, sum(1 for _ in group)) for label, group in groups]
    for i in range(0,len(result)):
        p.append(result[i][1])
    print (max(p)+1)
    p=[]
    num+=1
```

The question says that the first line contains the number of test cases.Each of the following line contains each test case which I am taking as input one by one,as mentioned in the question.Still it is giving the same error.The problem is I frequently encounter NZEC error while using Python as the language in Codechef.

Comment: What is the code *supposed* to do? Which "Codechef" challenge is it? What is the challenge problem statement? Please provide some context as to how to give inputs to the program and what those inputs should be...When I run the code I just see a prompt for user input. How do I make it give a `"znec"` error?

Comment: I am sorry,this would provide some context:https://www.codechef.com/JULY17/problems/CHEFSIGN

Comment: No worries, Thank you for providing the link to the problem statement. What inputs cause a non-zero exit code? When I run the script, I get `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 11, in <module>
    groups=groupby(y)
NameError: name 'y' is not defined`

Comment: for each test case, how many lines do you input? the problem statement shows each test case should be contained in only *one* line of input, but your code seems to be taking each character input one line at a time. I'm not sure if that is related to the `ZNEC` error you are getting, but it may prevent your code from passing test cases if the test engine gives input all in *one single* line.

Comment: The question says that each test case would contain one single line and hence the test cases should be present in their own lines.Even if that were the problem, shouldn't it give an NZEC on each test input and not on the selected few?

Comment: I ran your code and got similar errors, I think the errors relate to the constraints in the problem statement `Subtask #1 (30 points): 1 ≤ T, |s| ≤ 105
1 ≤ Sum of |s| over all test cases in a single test file ≤ 106`. I'm not sure how to limit the input to meet those constraints though.

Answer (score 0):

**PUT ALL CODE IN TRY EXCEPT BCZ CODECHEF USE FILE AS AN INPUT I DID IN MY CODE AND IT'S WORKS**

```
    from itertools import groupby
    try:
        counter=int(input())
        arg=[]
        p=[]
        for i in range(int(counter)):
            arg.append(input())
        num=0
        while (num<counter):
            x=arg[num]
            l=x.replace('=','')
            groups=groupby(y)
            result = [(label, sum(1 for _ in group)) for label, group in groups]
            for i in range(0,len(result)):
                p.append(result[i][1])
            print (max(p)+1)
            p=[]
            num+=1
    except:
        pass
```